# upload only jpg and png format images in database through php

Tags: php, mysql

If an uploaded image is other than `jpg` and `png` format file, insertion of values into database will not work and form will not get submitted.

```
  $extensions= array("jpeg","jpg");

  if(in_array($file_ext,$extensions)=== false) {
      $errors[]="extension not allowed, please choose a JPEG or PNG file.";
  }

  if(empty($errors)==true) {
      move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,$file_name);
      echo "Success";
  } 
  else {
      print_r($errors);
  }
```

Comment: And so ? any problem, error ? thing ?

Comment: Does your <form> element contain enctype="multipart/form-data" attribute?

Comment: Grammar and code formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$extensions= array("jpeg","jpg");
 $errors='';
  if(!in_array($file_ext,$extensions)){
 $errors="extension not allowed, please choose a JPEG or PNG file.";} 
 if($errors=='') {
     move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,$file_name);
     echo "Success";
  }else{
     print_r($errors);
  }}
```

Comment: A little explanation might be helpful. What is the problem and how does your code solve it?

Comment: He wants to accept  just jpeg and jpg files for uploading,And my code do this for his

Comment: `in_array($file_ext,$extensions)===false` and `empty($errors)==true` achieve the [same result](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/7uhw-13b2). I don't think those are causing problems in the OP's code.